# How to decrease Logstash Memory Usage

Tags: performance, memory-management, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am using Logstash-5.6.5 (in Windows) running in a standalone system (no cloud or cluster). Planning to watch some log files and post it to locally run elasticsearch. But when checked the Logstash's memory usage, without a configuration to watch any file it is showing around 600MB memory usage. When I add input file pipeline configurations further it adds memory futher (For watching 3 log files it added up to 70MB, but I am planning to add more upto 20 logs). 

1. Is it the expected behaviour? 

2. Is there any way to reduce the huge memory usage by logstash?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*After researching for couple of days below is my answer to my question.*

Below are the ways we can optimize Logstash memory:

1. Logstash memory usage is primarily getting accumulated by heap size. This can be effectively controlled by setting the heap memory size in the environment variable **LS_JAVA_OPTS** as below, before launching Logstash (for Windows version in my case):

   ```
   set "LS_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m –Xmx512m"
   ```

Otherwise may be this can be added in the setup.bat at the beginning of the file.

In this way I have limited Logstash total the memory usage to 620 MB maximum.

2. Logstash pipeline configurations (input/filter/output) can be optimized using the methods mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-configuration-tuning).

In this way I asserted whether my Logstash filter configurations are optimized.

3. Also pipeline input file configurations can be optimized using few properties below to ignore/close old log files as explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-ignore_older), which will prevent unnecessary creation of pipeline threads.

   - ignore_older - in seconds - to totally ignore any file older than the given seconds
   - max_open_files - in numbers - to optimize the maximum number of opened files
   - close_older - in seconds to close the older files
   - exclude - array of unwanted file names (with or without wildcard)

In my case I was required to watch the recent files only and ignore the older files, and I have set the configuration accordingly as below:

```
input {
  file {
    #The application log path that will match with the rolling logs.
    path => "c:/path/to/log/app-1.0-*.log"
    #I didn't want logs older than an hour.
    #If that older file gets updated with a new entry 
    #that will become the new file and the new entry will be read by Logstash
    ignore_older => 3600 

    #I wanted to have only the very recent files to be watched. 
    #Since I am aware there won't be more then 5 files I set it to 5.
    max_open_files => 5 

    #If the log file is not updated for 5 minutes close it. 
    #If any new entry gets added then it will be opened again.
    close_older => 300 
  }
}
```